# What happens when a Promise in a Promise.all, in a then chain fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When there is a .then chain that includes a Promise.all such as the following example, do the errors get caught in the final .catch block for the parent .then chain or do they require their own error handling?

```
.then(([user, booking]) => {
  const payment = { }

  return Promise.all([
    paymentService(payment),
    Promise.resolve(user),
    Promise.resolve(booking)
  ])
})
.then(([paid, user, booking]) => {
  return Promise.all([
    repo.makeBooking(user, booking),
    Promise.resolve(paid),
    Promise.resolve(user)
  ])
})
.catch((err) => {
    //Error handling here
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are returning a promise inside each `.then()`, the errors are chained to the main flow, so in your example, the `.catch` method will catch all errors.

Consider this example:

```
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then((n) => {
    return Promise.all([
      Promise.resolve(`a-${n}`),
      Promise.reject(Error('Failed in Promise.all')), // comment for success
    ]);
  })
  .then(([a, b]) => {
    const msg = `Responses: [${a}, ${b}]`;
    console.log(msg);
    return msg;
  })
  .catch((error) => { throw error; });
```

Here the inner `Promise.all()` has a reject that is caught by the parent flow.

> Read some about chaining promises here: **[#2 Nested Promises](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/#2nestedpromises)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are caught by the last (in your example) `catch()`.

---

You could also insert another `catch()` just after the `then()` with `Promise.all()`, and in that case both `catch()-es` would be called. The only catch with that is that you would have to manually "rethrow" the error from the first `catch()`:

```
.then(([user, booking]) => {
  const payment = { }

  return Promise.all([
    paymentService(payment),
    Promise.resolve(user),
    Promise.resolve(booking)
  ])
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Error handling logic...

  // Rethrow the error to allow the second catch to... catch it
  throw error;
})
.then(([paid, user, booking]) => {
  return Promise.all([
    repo.makeBooking(user, booking),
    Promise.resolve(paid),
    Promise.resolve(user)
  ])
})
.catch((err) => {
    //Error handling here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `.catch()` gets the value of a promise that is rejected.
`Promise.prototype.catch(myHandler)` is the same thing as calling `Promise.prototype.then(undefined, myHandler)`. So it

For promises that are chained with `.then()`, what that means is that if the previous promise fails, then the subsequent rejected callback is called.

So if you have a the following code:

```
Promise.resolve().then((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('this is the first promise');
  reject();
}).then(() => {
  console.log('this is the second promise');
  reject();
}).catch((value) => {
  console.log('this is the third promise')
});
```

The output is:

> this is the first promise
>
> this is the third promise

The reason for that is follows: Promise.resolve() creates a promise. Let's number that as promise #1.

Note that `.then` returns a *new* promise equal to the return of the inner promise. So by calling `.then()` on line 1, we create promise #2. The second `.then()` call creates promise #3.

Okay. Now that's set up, Promise #1 is already resolved, so it calls into the success case. That's why 'this is the first promise' prints. We then reject promise #2 inside the handler.

Promise #2 has one handler on it (with the body 'this is the second promise'). Since Promise #2 is rejected, this handler does not run. ** The way chained promises works means that this also causes Promise #3 to be rejected **. Therefore when we get to the `catch()` handler, it runs the `this is the third promise` example.

You can read more here for more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch